# How to start solr server in hybris 5.7 in standalone mode?

Tags: spring-mvc, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Unable to start solr server in hybris 5.7 so search is not working . How to start solr server in hybris 5.7 in standalone mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `hybris\bin\ext-commerce\solrserver\resources\solr\bin`run `solr start`.

Note that it's the path from version 6. The installation dir might be different, it is the location where the Solr installation bundle has been extracted.

Take a look at the README in solr/server to have the details about the config,log dir etc...

Also take a look at `solr -help`

> Usage: solr COMMAND OPTIONS
>          where COMMAND is one of: start, stop, restart, healthcheck, create, create_core, create_collection, delete, version, upconfig, downconfig
>
> Standalone server example (start Solr running in the background on port 8984):
>       solr start -p 8984
>
> SolrCloud example (start Solr running in SolrCloud mode using localhost:2181 to connect to Zookeeper, with 1g max heap size and remote Java debug options enabled):
>
> solr start -c -m 1g -z localhost:2181 -a "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044"
>
> Pass -help after any COMMAND to see command-specific usage information,
>     such as:    solr start -help or solr stop -help

Comment: D:\Hybris_5.7_merchendise_new\hybris\bin\ext-commerce\solrserver\resources\solr\bin>solr stop -p 8983
SET was unexpected at this time.

Comment: D:\Hybris_5.7_merchendise_new\hybris\bin\ext-commerce\solrserver\resources\solr\bin>solr start -p 8983
SET was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Unfortunnately I don't have version 5.7 to check the content of script `solr`. Can you find out the line in error?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the fine answers above, let me mention all steps, which required to set up the standalone Solr server in SAP Hybris.

### Prerequestion

- `solrserver` extension should be there in your `localextensions.xml` file

### Hybris OOTB Solr configuration background

The default configuration is as follows:

```
solrserver.instances.default.autostart=true
solrserver.instances.default.mode=standalone
solrserver.instances.default.hostname=localhost
solrserver.instances.default.port=8983
solrserver.instances.default.memory=512m
```

Here, you can see `autostart=true` which tell Solr server to start and stop together with the Hybris platform.

---

### Setup external Standalone Server

We want to start/stop it independently from Hybris instance. To do so we need disables the autostart for the default Solr instance using below properties.

```
solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false

solrserver.instances.standalone.autostart=true
solrserver.instances.standalone.mode=standalone
solrserver.instances.standalone.hostname=localhost
solrserver.instances.standalone.port=8983
solrserver.instances.standalone.memory=512m
```

---

### How to start/stop solr server

You can simply use ***ant commands*** to start and stop solr server

```
ant startSolrServer
ant stopSolrServer
```

Hybris OOTB, you can find solr setup at `hybris/bin/ext-commerce/solrserver/resources/solr/`.   Now go to `bin` folder, there you can also run solr script manually as mentioned below.

**Start the solr server**

```
./solr start -p 8983    #Linux systems
solr.cmd start -p 8983  #Window system
```

**Stop the solr server**

```
./solr stop -p 8983    #Linux systems
solr.cmd stop -p 8983  #Window system
```

---

### Find [detail post here](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/install-standalone-solr-in-hybris.html)

Answer (score 0):

The **solrserver** extension provides some additional ant tasks that can be used to control the **Solr** instances and servers.

Following ant commands can be used

startSolrServer - Starts a Solr server.

stopSolrServer - Stops a Solr server.